# Which dumplings will be more salty?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, everyday-life, water

There are two identical pots filled with different amounts of water (one has more water, the other one has less). The same amount of salt has been poured to each pot.

The same amount of dumplings has been put in each pot (and cooked but I don't think that matters). Which portion of dumplings will be more salty (if any)?

Comment: Hi NPS, welcome to Physics SE. Please read the [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) of this site. You have to show some effort in this type of questions and ask about a specific point of your problem.

Comment: First of all, this is not a homework. It's an everyday life problem that has been bugging me for some time. Second, the question is so simple (not easy to answer, but simple in its form) that I can't answer a part of it and show it to you - either I answer the whole question or none at all. Besides, I simply have no idea what the answer might be.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the homework tag, there is a [meta discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4977/should-we-rename-the-homework-tag-as-problem-solving-or-such?cb=1) whether to rename it. It refers to "problem solving" questions.

Comment: Yeah, I read that. But until you do, it's not a homework question. Also my other reason stands.

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] or [cooking.se] be better homes for this question?

Comment: Concerning chemistry, I would say this is a question of osmotic pressure and or diffusion either of which is well placed in physics or physical chemistry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer I will make two assumptions: in both pots the amount of water is enough 1) to get all the salt into solution and 2) to not get absorbed completely by the dumplings.

Say pot A has less water than pot B than the concentration of salt in pot A will be higher. If the dumplings are initially dry, they will absorb water and the dumplings in pot A will absorb, therefore, more salt. If the dumplings already contain water (which is likely to be the case), there will be diffusion of salt into the non salty part. Due to the bigger concentration gradient, the dumplings in pot A will get more salt in a shorter time. 
At the end the dumplings in pot A should have a higher amount of salt and taste more salty.

I guess making an extreme example, makes it intuitive. Instead of two similar pots where the amount of water only differs by some percentage, take a normal pot where the dumplings just fit (A) and as a second pot (B) you take an Olympic swimming pool. Put a spoon of salt in each and place the dumplings. It is reasonable that the first case will result in salty dumplings while the second case does not.

By the way, this even stays true, if one starts with very salty dumplings in the first place. The salt diffusion is just the other way around but the gradient argument is the same.

Comment: `the dumplings in pot A will get more salt in a shorter time` - Is it still true if the dumplings stay in the water for a very long time (or infinitely long assuming they wouldn't dissolve in the water :P)?

Comment: Assuming the pots do not dry out, yes. I would say it is a simple question of concentration. To make it less "cooking" and more physics, one could take sponges instead of dumplings. They could be either dry or full of sweet water. Case 1 sucks up higher concentrated water, case 2 higher gradient; same as before. Case 2 roughly approaches case 1 for infinite times (slightly modified concentration though due to the additional water)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the pot with less water you'll have more salt spread through a smaller volume than the other pot. That means the *water* will be saltier in the pot with less water. I don't know the salt transfer rate for a solution to dumplings, but I would assume the one with a higher salt-to-water ratio would be saltier.